# How to time how long a user spends in an Activity

Tags: android, time, android-activity

What would be the best way to time how long a user spends in a specific Activity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I'd start out with something like this:

```
private static long mTotalTime;
private long mStartTime;

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mTotalTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Note that because it's using onPause/onResume it will also 'pause' the timer if the screen turns off, if it re-orients etc. Depending on what your purpose is you may want to use one of the other callbacks like onCreate() or onDestroy(), but note that onDestroy() doesn't alway get called when a new activity launches from the existing activity.

You may also want to save mTotalTime to SharedPreferences so that it is preserved even if the app is shut down. Maybe something like this:

```
private long mStartTime;

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    int totalTime = getPreferences(0).getInt("TotalTime",0);
    getPreferences(0).edit().putInt("TotalTime", totalTime + System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime)
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Start / stop your time keeping in the Activity's `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods. Also install a SCREEN_OFF / SCREEN_ON broadcast receiver so you know when the screen comes on and off and enable/disable your timing there as well.

Comment: Is onPause() automatically called when the screen turns off?

Comment: I am not certain if onPause() is called when the screen turns off, but the Activity Lifecycle suggests it only gets called when another activity takes over focus, and even when using a lock screen, this does not happen as a result of the screen going off / back on.

Comment: @mah, I thought it does get called. Else network threads etc would keep running. Although maybe you would want this to be true, so inactivity doesnt interrupt anything. Hmm. Something to test. Edit, although you wouldnt want gaming threads to keep running..?